# Java 7 MySQL connections some times taking long time to close

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

We have an application hosted on Tomcat 7 using java 7 and backend is MySql 5.1.62.

Sometimes the application is hanging while closing the idle database connections which are opened for about 2-3 hours in the connection pool and throwing the error:

```
Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction
resolution unknown.
```

This is not happening all the times and we are seeing this behaviour randomly.

Thank you in advance for any response.

Note: MySQL wait_timeout is set to 8 days.

Comment: Which framework you are using? Are you able to retrieve hanging transactions and why are they caused?

Comment: It is an old application and it uses 3-tier architecture. The application closes the connections which exceeds the 1 hr idle time from pool and the application is hanging at connection.close() statement sometimes.

Comment: Not the expert but 1 hour sounds too long for me, how you handle stale connections? i.e. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm#CFHHCICE

Comment: First we are checking the idle time of that connection and if it exceeds 1 hr then the below code we are using to close that connection and replace with new: `if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
         connection.close();
        }`

Comment: MySQL wait_timeout and ConnectionTimeOut does not seems to be usual. This will definitely showing the issues you stated. If not necessary, reduceon the both the times. Or Use some framework like hibernate which will take care of these things.